# cake php--- password hashing

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using this in my controller

```
public $components = array(`enter code here`
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

this is reffered from book:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

and this in my model

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!$this->id) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data['User']['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Ok. What is the question ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to hash the password:

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = 
    AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
```

Since AuthComponent::password() is visible everywhere.

At least if this is what you are asking for. Agree with Shankar that question is missing.